# "Not sufficiently replicated yet" when appending to a file in HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I have a version 2.4.1 cluster running, with 1 namenode and 4 datanodes (namenode being one of them).
I am running a Java program that appends data to a file in HDFS every second. Currently the file size is about 100 GB. My replication factor is 2.

I have lately started having problems with appending data to the file. Every time my program tries to append to the file, I get exception `org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): append: lastBlock=blk_1073742660_2323939 of src=/user/hduser/siridata.txt is not sufficiently replicated yet.`

If I run fsck it says the file is corrupt - missing one block. Sometimes the filesystem gets healthy with a random combination of running `balancer`/`namenode recovery`/`hdfs dfs -setrep`. After running the append for a while, the original problem reappears. I even once removed one node already which had corrupt data and the system got 100 % healthy without any problems - for a while.

I also tried to start using a new file for the data, but the same problem persists.

Any ideas what could be wrong? Thanks!

Comment: have you tried decreasing replication factor to 1? Error message clearly says that replicaiton is a problem: you are changing file faster than it's replicated by hdfs.

Comment: I was digging some logs and found a `checksum error` in one of the slaves before this main error. So I guess whenever the first transmission problem occurs, hadoop doesn't have time anymore to recover from it.
If that's the case, then changing replication factor might work, but would only help temporarily. I would encounter the same problem later. Does this mean I simply cannot append data this fast into HDFS?

Comment: Also someone suggested that this could be about a race condition when writing to the file. I guess the Hadoop jar-runner wouldn't cause that, so it would need to be something in my code. Will try to investigate, even if the code itself is quite simple.

Comment: I ended up deciding that I encountered this bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-6804 . Will try to go around the problem with buffering or so.